# Issue in jquery while making table row clickable which contain Link in table data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which contains a link as a table data, I want to make table row click-able. For this I use the following jQuery.

Functionality of this is like

1. When clicking on row it calls a action and the data for that will show in new window.
2. When you click on table data link it will open link in new window and no action for row click.

Code:

```
jQuery( function($) {
    $('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click( function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('data-href'),'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=1240,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
    }).find('a').hover( function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');
    }, function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').click( function() {
            window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
        });
    });
});
```

Now issue is that when I first click on table data link and after that I click on table row it is not opening in new window but the current page redirect to the page which expected to be open in new window.

Comment: you mean to say that, say I clicked row 1: I see row1 popup and now I click row 2: row1 popup is replaced with row2 content ?

Comment: Open a popup if a row is clicked. If the row has a link and you hover it, unbind the click event (so no popup should open), and finally if you hover out, then load the url in the current page. Is this are you trying to do? And the url is not opening within the current page?

Comment: click on table row will open link in popup window and other one which table data link, when we click on this link this will open in other popup window

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the wrong way.

Instead of messing around with unbinding and rebinding the click event, just handle the events for the anchor elements as well and check in the handler function itself what has been clicked and perform proper action. New code would be:

```
jQuery( function($) {
    $('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable');
    $('tbody').on('click', 'tr[data-href],a', function(evt) {
        if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
            document.location = this.href;
        }
        else {
            window.open($(this).attr('data-href'),'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=1240,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
        }
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/QTxqr/4/).

Comment: So just change `document.location =` to `window.open(` can't see what's the problem?

Comment: thanks for your comment "window.open($(this).attr('data-href'),'mywin'" and +1 for it.